# Access (Read and Write) Local File/Directory from Browser

Tags: scripting, read-write, browser-plugin, access-rights, local-files

I know its `not possible to access a local file/directory via scripting` because of security reasons but may be there exist a way to access local file/directory, like `via Browser Plugin` or `some module (*.exe files) that can send data from local directory to browser` etc.

Please note I'm `not talking about file:///*` but read/write access to local directories/files. Please share your experience and idea(s) on number of possibilities to achieve this goal.

Comment: What is it your trying to achieve? If you want to store data at the client maybe html5 local storage is an option. If you want to make an app that modifies local data, maybe a webapp isn't the right course of action and a desktop app would be a better option.

Comment: I have developed online editor for php. I want to make it better than my existing IDE and for that I want to somehow access local files. That is stage 2 of my online editor and seems most difficult stage. All other stages seems simpler